Keeping related column data grouped in ClickHouse materialized views
I'm working with UTM session event data in a ClickHouse table, and implementing a materialized view that aggregates data by session across multiple platforms.
The UTM data is coming in as a JSON payload, and expanded via:
SELECT
    session_id,
    ....
    coalesce(JSONExtractString(sessionPayload, 'utm_source'), '') as utm_source,
    coalesce(JSONExtractString(sessionPayload, 'utm_medium'), '') as utm_medium,
    coalesce(JSONExtractString(sessionPayload, 'utm_campaign'), '') as utm_campaign,
    coalesce(JSONExtractString(sessionPayload, 'utm_content'), '') as utm_content,
    coalesce(JSONExtractString(sessionPayload, 'utm_term'), '') as utm_term

It is then rolled-up in an aggregation pipe inserting into a meterialized view:
SELECT
  anySimpleState(
    tuple(
      coalesce(utm_source, '') as utm_source,
      coalesce(utm_medium, '') as utm_medium,
      coalesce(utm_campaign, '') as utm_campaign,
      coalesce(utm_content, '') as utm_content,
      coalesce(utm_term, '') as utm_term
    )
  ) AS utm

This is the schema of the materialized view:
SCHEMA
  `utm` SimpleAggregateFunction(any, Tuple(String, String, String, String, String))

My goal is to make sure that ute parameters are consistently kept as a group (hence tuple) during aggregation, and that the first UTM group encountered (any).
My question is if there's a better way to approach this requirement without constructing the tuples, which make dynamic filtering more challenging further down the line.
Thanks!

any reason you cant simply GROUP BY utm_source, utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_content, utm_term ? and compute statistics  by these. Its unclear what you're trying to achieve with the Mv.

You can probably try doing SELECT ... group by session_id

any function works on row level, so you will keep consistent fields inside tuple after SELECT ... FINAL
